# Change the form of existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change the form of existing dataframe to a new dataframe such that the value in the new dataframe matches the relationship of the existing two columns. Hence, in the new dataframe, "1" means there is a record in the existing dataframe and "0" means no record.

This is what I did so far. Basically through manual judging but this won't work when I have more than 1000 rows.

---

Existing dataframe:

```
series_1 = [[19,"a"],[20,"d"],[31,"d"],[31,"c"],[51,"d"]]
a_df = pd.DataFrame(series_1)
```

[image: Existing dataframe]

---

Desired dataframe:

```
cols = ["a","c","d"]
series_3 = [1,0,0,
           0,0,1,
           0,1,1,
           0,0,1]
np_series = np.array(series_3).reshape(4,3)
c_df = pd.DataFrame(np_series,index = [19,20,31,51],columns=cols)
```

[image: Desired format of dataframe]

---

I'm wondering what are some good ways to transform the dataframe according to above request. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
pd.crosstab(a_df[0], a_df[1])
```

Result:

```
1   a   c   d
0           
19  1   0   0
20  0   0   1
31  0   1   1
51  0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick Answer to your Question

```py
import pandas as pd

dic = {
    '0': [19,20,31,31,51],
    '1': ['a','d','d','c','d']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic) #Creating a dataframe

unique_vals = df['1'].unique().tolist() # Finding unique values from desired column

for val in unique_vals:
    df[val] = list(map(lambda item: 1 if item==val else 0,df['1'])) # Mapping to a new column

df.set_index('0', inplace = True) # Setting index
df.drop(['1'],axis = 1, inplace =True) #! Only use this line if you want to delete '1' column

print(df)
```

> Output

```
 0  a   d   c
        
19  1   0   0
20  0   1   0
31  0   1   0
31  0   0   1
51  0   1   0
```